# Maps api android key for places api not work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Google maps api for android v2 work with key i created using sha1, but when i put this key in the google places api search string my result is ACCESS DENIED.

Also in the google apis console report i see that i got called for places api.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Both the keys are different, get your places API key [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

Comment: your link place my in the overview google api console where i created my maps keys. how do i get places key?

Comment: Login with your userId, then create a project by clicking the left top corner drop down box and then choosing your appropriate API you want to use.

Comment: got it. i opened new project and it work. I feel kind of dumb, but it no so clear :) Thanks man